# How do i input Arabic text into my python code?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

my project is to identify a sentiment either positive or negative ( sentiment analysis ) in Arabic language,to do this task I used NLTK and python, when I enter tweets in arabic an error  occurs

```
>>> pos_tweets = [(' أساند كل عون أمن شريف', 'positive'),
              ('ما أحلى الثورة التونسية', 'positive'),
              ('أجمل طفل في العالم', 'positive'),
              ('الشعب يحرس', 'positive'),
              ('ثورة شعبنا هي ثورة الكـــرامة وثـــورة الأحــــرار', 'positive')]
Unsupported characters in input
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you give more details about your system?

Comment: my project is to build a sentiment analysis toolkit for Arabic language, when I browsed the net I found that this task is more tough than english language , I found an example which deal with NLTK and python to analyse sentiment and it gives a good result [example](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/) , I'm wondering if I can do the same thing for arabic language

Comment: Sorry, I mean are you running from interactive shell or from a script? Which python shell did you use, what is your OS, etc.

Comment: I 'm runnig from IDLE shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem came from the IDLE shell. AFAIK IDLE won't accept UTF-8 input in interactive mode.

I suggest youe use alternative (and better) shells such as [DreamPie](http://www.dreampie.org/) or [PythonWin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/).

Comment: are these tools able to analyse sentiment in arabic language (is there api for stop words, classificatio ....)?

Comment: They're just shells. They will just pass whatever statement you type into the Python interpreter. Using whatever shell you like wouldn't pose any problem. Of course you still have to install the required library (nltk in this case).

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple hack that i usually do to input `UTF-8` into my python code. I don't know why it works but it accepts the unicode strings and runs the script smoothly after I add these lines:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python  -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

pos_tweets = [(u' أساند كل عون أمن شريف', 'positive'), 
(u'ما أحلى الثورة التونسية', 'positive'), 
(u'أجمل طفل في العالم', 'positive'), 
(u'الشعب يحرس', 'positive'), 
(u'ثورة شعبنا هي ثورة الكـــرامة وثـــورة الأحــــرار', 'positive')] 

for i in pos_tweets:
  print i[0], i[1]
```