# How to do a coding ( Arabic إعراب Parsing) Python?

Tags: python, nlp

I need to do a python program that includes إعراب القرآن الكريم

For example 
input (يلعب الطفل  ) 
output ( 
يلعب فعل مضارع مرفوع و علامة رفعه الضمة الظاهرة على اخره
الطفل فاعل مرفوع وعلامة رفعه الضمة الظاهرة على اخره
)

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: I was curious how python handles right-to-left text as an identifier. After typing in `إعر`  `= 1 my console switched it to ` إعر=1` but it assigned the value just fine. I now have a new way to obscure my programs! - and smiled again when it reversed in this comment.

Comment: If you mean includes as a string, python source defaults to UTF-8. As long as your editor or IDE save to utf-8, there is nothing else needed. For other encodings see [PEP263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Answer (score 1):

It could be based on your IDE... 
[How do i input Arabic text into my python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196321/how-do-i-input-arabic-text-into-my-python-code)

Try using a different IDE that supports UTF-8 if you aren't already. If the problem is when opening a file, make sure to specify `encoding='utf-8'` when opening it

Comment: If the OP is using Python 2, there's the header: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to tell Python 2 the content is UTF-8.  This is the default for Python 3, so the header is not necessary.